# Использование яндекс директ api

Tags: яндекс-директ

Подскажите как использовать API яндекс директа. Я все что не пробовал, не получалось чтобы заработало.

Приведите хоть какой-нить пример использования функций без авторизации и использования токенов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как по мне, у данного API достаточно приличная [документация](http://api.yandex.ru/direct/) на русском яязыке, в конце которой, кстати говоря, есть много примеров на различных языках программирования.